# A word to describe someone or something that is not last?

Tags: adjectives

I'm looking for a word that describes the state of not being last. A word that would apply to everything in an ordered list that is not the last thing in that list.

From

> I wasn't the last person to finish the race.

to (the phrasing is off, but it seems to illustrate my point)

> I was .. person to finish the race.

One word that comes to mind is "intermediate", but I don't think that includes the first item in a list.

Comment: "I was the second to last to finish the race" has as an example "I was the fifty-seventh person to finish the race, out of 58".

Comment: OP is looking for a word like _penultimate_ but for the rest of the list bar the last - perhaps non-ultimate

Comment: I doubt there is a term that defines all positions except the last.

Comment: I'm not aware of a single word that expresses this idea. I'd just say "all but the last" or similar.

Comment: @mplungjan, exactly right. I'm looking to describe an object that has the only defining property of not being last in a list of similar objects. "Not last X" doesn't really sound right.

Comment: non-losing participant :)

Comment: Could you say "exists in the *head* of the list"? Note the preposition *in*, as opposed to *at*, which would indicate the very first item, specifically). It wouldn't be confusing to say the item appeared in the *tail* of the list to mean "not first", so perhaps "in the head" would work for "not last".

Comment: You could try using "anteultimate" (not *antepenultimate*, which means 3rd to last), though that would effectively be to coin a word (i.e. no one else uses it or has used it).

Comment: @DanBron *anteultimate* would be understood as **penultimate,** by anyone other than, well, what? "Director Fernando Di Leo’s anteultimate feature film before his filmmaking career ended in 1985 ..." (On soiledsinema: http://www.soiledsinema.com/2013/11/madness-1980.html?zx=417e76d05c6b79d8) See also: https://community.gaslampgames.com/threads/make-all-levers-in-the-roomsdb-unpushable.5801/ http://www.forgottenbooks.com/readbook_text/The_Grenville_Papers_v3_1000707955/225

Comment: comment because it's (possibly) not a real word, but has usage support: [pre-final](https://www.google.com/search?q=pre-final)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In formal writing, esp., in the fields of programming, linguistics, the word **non-final** is already in use.

On Stackoverflow (java):

> [What is (a) **non-final** variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455994/what-is-non-final-variable)

In René Kager, [*A Metrical Theory of Stress and Destressing in English and Dutch*](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=y4UpbijZVysC&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=%22non-final%20syllable%22&source=bl&ots=QtjO47LhKE&sig=-HWhIzVk4Yf87cmQvvJFy1itVEQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KcoFVNaLGNGQuASGrIGABQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22non-final%20syllable%22&f=false) (Lingistics) -- Google Books:

> … if the rightmost stress is on the final syllable, the primary stress can either be on the final syllable (112a), or on the rightmost stressed **non-final** syllable (112b) … [emphasis added]

---

[EDIT]
See also ***** :
[medial](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/medial) on ODO

> 1.2 Phonetics (Of a speech sound) in the middle of a word:
>   *A total of 15 items were included on this task requiring students to delete initial, **medial**, and final phonemes from words* [emphasis added]

Although *medial,* tends to suggest something closer to the middle, it's not necessarily so. In the example above, anything that is not *initial* or *final* is referred to as *medial.*

***** However, *medial* **excludes** the initial, which is why it is not a candidate for the OP's case.

Comment: While this answer could be slightly confusing in context (as I'm  looking for a way to name a Java variable and non-final does not refer to order there), it fits perfectly.

Comment: +1 But when your getting close to the end, you can always fall back on those commonplace terms, penultimate and antepenultimate.

Comment: @bib *penultimate* and similar words are specific to a **single** position and thus cannot apply to a general case of 'other than the last.'

Comment: @Kris That is why I said *when you're getting close to the end ...* [misspelled in the original]. They are both explicit to position. That is why it was offered as a [tongue-in-cheek] comment rather than an answer. And I realize my cheeks were not visible, but I hate emoticons.

Comment: The stack overflow reference is incorrect. The terms final and non-final in that context are closer synonyms to static and dynamic, as opposed to last and not-last.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "also-ran" springs to mind which, although is directly referencing a running race, has also come to mean "one of the many other competitors that was not placed first" in any general competition not necessarily just running...

Example: "I was one of the also-rans..."

Comment: This word describes the property of not being first. I'm looking for something both more general and something that describes the property of not being last.