# What's a synonym for "not last"

Tags: synonyms

If I want to indicate that the current batch of items isn't the last one, what's one generic word to say "not last"?

P.S. Not looking for a specific word e.g. penultimate

Comment: If you want the opposite of 'not last', then the answer is 'last'.

Comment: @WS2 Sorry, my bad. Fixed the title.

Comment: How about, _Subsequent_?.

Comment: Why not "not last"? Why do you need another word? I don't think there is a better way to say.

Comment: @SrJoven : That was useful. My title was incorrect initially else it would have shown up in search.

Comment: If you mean by "current batch" that it's the latest but that more will follow, I'd just say "current," "latest" or "newest" because they all imply to me that more batches are to follow.

Answer (score 5):

Not last is *non-terminal*. Simple as that.

(Sometimes it is called *intermediate*: an *intermediate* item in a series is neither the first nor the last.)

But I second @Papa Poule's comment that if you are trying to distinguish the **most recent** but **not necessarily** the last, then use *latest*.

Comment: I'll second your second with an upvote and the following: 'Latest' (or even 'current') doesn't necessarily exclude 'initial' (which OP buffer prefers not to do): "Granted, we're just starting out and our first batch is our latest, but I can promise you that it won't be our last." and "We are currently working on our first batch.", as examples.

Answer (score 2):

"on-going"

"On-going batch" will indicate that there's more to come.

Also, "non-final," but that's too formal here.

Comment: I like `medial` from your answer here, although I wish there was something similar that doesn't exclude 'initial' : http://english.stackexchange.com/a/194527/64611

Answer (score 1):

**Forerunner** ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/forerunner))

> 1. predecessor; ancestor; forebear; precursor

**Precursor** ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/precursor))

> 1. a person or thing that precedes, as in a job, a method, etc.; predecessor

**Ancestor** ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ancestor?s=t))

> 3. an object, idea, style, or occurrence serving as a prototype, forerunner, or inspiration to a later one

If your talking about batches of things, where order isn't important, but completeness is, then these words might help:

*Unfinished, incomplete, short, shy.**